Expo background fetch function not triggering
I am using expo-background-fetch(11.8.1) and expo-task-manager(11.7.2) using the example given in the expo documents. I am able to register a new task. But it is not being triggered. I am testing it in real iOS device using dev client build. I am using expo 50.0.14.
I can manually trigger the function using the Instruments app as given in the docs. I have also waited for around 20 mins to see if it is an issue caused by the OS. Phone was plugged in so that battery level won't cause any issue. Still the function is not being triggered.
